# Dataframe does not correctly reshape

Tags: r, label, reshape, tidyverse, hmisc

I have the following dataframe:

```
  Variables Varcode  Country Ccode  2000  2001 
1 Power     P        France  FR     1213  1234
2 Happiness H        France  FR     1872  2345
3 Power     P        UK      UK     1726  6433
4 Happiness H        UK      UK     2234  9082

I would like to reshape this dataframe as follows:

  Year      Country Ccode P(label=Power) H(label=Happiness)
1 2000      France  FR    1213          1872  
2 2001      France  FR    1234          2345
3 2000      UK      UK    1726          2234
4 2001      UK      UK    6433          9082
```

The original code was as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(Year, val, -Variables, -Country) %>%
    spread(Variables, val)
```

I tried to expand the code because, the `Ccode` and `Indicator Code` ended up as a row in the list and I decided I wanted to use the codes as variable names and the variable names as labels (please note that because of that I swapped `-Variables` and `Variables` with `-Varcode` and `Varcode` respectively):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)
List <- df$Variables
df<-df %>%
    gather(Year, val, -Varcode, -Country) %>%
    spread(Varcode, val)
for(i in List){
label(df[,i]) <- List[i]
}
```

Please note: I am using a list because of memory limitations.

I ran into two problems:

1. The transformation does not go smoothly because two additional columns from `df`(among which `Variables`) are added where values should be.
2. The label function gives an error.

Can anyone help me figuring out what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you went wrong with your selection of columns to gather

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Variables Varcode  Country  2000  2001 
1 Power     P        France   1213  1234
2 Happiness H        France   1872  2345
3 Power     P        UK       1726  6433
4 Happiness H        UK       2234  9082", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  rename(`2000` = X2000, `2001` = X2001)
```

---

```
df %>% 
  select(-Varcode) %>% 
  gather(Year, val,`2000`:`2001`) %>% 
  unite(Country_Ccode, Country, Ccode, sep = "_") %>% 
  spread(Variables, val) %>% 
  separate(Country_Ccode, c("Country", "Ccode"), sep = "_")
```

Output

```
  Country Ccode Year Happiness Power
1  France    FR 2000      1872  1213
2  France    FR 2001      2345  1234
3      UK    UK 2000      2234  1726
4      UK    UK 2001      9082  6433
```

Comment: It seems that the code actually did work, but that the previous code had a similar problem. I will update the problem. Maybe you could take a second look? Also the list/label part does not really work.

Comment: I don't under what you are trying to achieve, please add what the dataframe should look like at the end

Comment: I have done so in my edit. My mistake was to not show the complete dataframe, my apologies for that.

Comment: See update. What is your need for `label`? I imagine that doesn't work for column names.

Comment: The actual dataset has about 1540 variables which have the worst indicator names (extremely long) and codes (not understandable). The idea would be that I can use the indicator codes to refer to the variable while still being able to understand what I am referring to.

Comment: So I got through part 1, many thanks! Any clue how to fix the label issue?

Comment: Since its a different question you should ask a separate question. But I would use the Varcode during analysis, then have something like a named list that maps Varcode to the original Variables if you need to look them up (for whatever reason)